# Can't delete node using Neo4j + Spring Data for Neo

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have added delete functionality for simple kind of node in my application

```
public class Vote extends BaseEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_FOR, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Criterion criterion;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;
```

Also, some other node entities having incoming relation to Vote

Delete query looks like this

```
"MATCH ()-[r]-(v:Vote) WHERE id(v) = {voteId} DELETE r,v"
```

When you doing delete all goes fine, no exception, when i trying to find all vote nodes from node entity referenced this vote before delete, result is as expected all votes except one i deleted are returned

But when i trying to find deleted vote by id i get not expected exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _)
```

Find work ok for other nodes, Probably it is related to SDN I don't know

Seems like I don't know how properly delete node or something, please help

Comment: Don't understand your questy, why don't you use repository.delete() or template.delete ? Also what do you mean with "But when i trying to find deleted vote by id i get not expected exception"

Comment: 1. I'm not using repocitory delete cos I want predict all dependencies and relatetions delete as well, or i can effectively use something like cascading? 2. So i successfuly deleted vote using my query, after i checking in my test to find vote i deleted by its id, i expect to have something like null result or NotFoundException but i geting java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _)

Comment: It should automatically delete all rels as well but no transitive cascading.

Comment: Something breaks in your stuff, that removes labels from your nodes.

Comment: Possible this query is deleting too much? I see in cypher query executor that among Vote nodes, neo has _Vote nodes? why they appear? Any ideas? possible some functionality of SDN